# running sudo without password

Tags: sudo, password

I'm running Manjaro Linux and I've got the following entries in my sudoers file:

```
$ sudo grep -vE '^#|^$' /etc/sudoers
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And my user is part of the 'wheel' group:

```
$ groups
sys network power vboxusers lp wheel user
```

How come I still get asked for a password whenever I run sudo?

Also, suppose my username is '**user**' and I only have `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` in the sudoers file. This was the original setting and I was able to run sudo commands even though there is nothing defined for '**user**' in this file. How does this work?

Comment: Look in `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Thanks @muru that makes sense, I do see a file there called 10-installer with wheel group defined